# prevent repopulating viewdata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Having populated a ViewData, is it possiblie to use that ViewData collection from multiple action methods within a controller without the need to repopulate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `ViewData` is not intended to be used that way. It is only a temporary shared storage between a controller action and a view. It allows the controller to pass some model to the view. From design perspective `ViewData` should not be read by the controller action, it should only be written to.

You could use the `Session` object if you want to store objects between multiple requests or `TempData` (which internally uses Session) to store data between two requests.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can if you store the data in some persistent storage between calls (like Session or some sort of cache for example). though i don't recommend that approach sometimes is necessary for long lived data that is needed everywhere and does not change very often.